# Azure Dev Ops add field Remaining work in backlog

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

is there a possibility to add the field "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" on backlog level? I would like to have a field with remaining work in the backlog, so that the work can be entered there directly without creating a work item.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIpNq.png)

Azure DevOps Server version: Version Dev17.M153.3

I added following lines in Bug.xml:

```xml
<FIELD name="Verbleibende Arbeit" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum" />
```

```xml
<Group Label="Details">
  <Control Label="Verbleibende Arbeit" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" />
  <Control Label="Aufwand" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
  <Control Label="Schweregrad" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" />
</Group>
```

Comment: Hi Julian, when you mention "...on backlog level", I'm not clear on what you're referring to. Could you elaborate?

Comment: With backlog level, I mean the parent work item type to a normal work task. A work item itself already has the property "Remaining work".This property is then summed up in the parent element (backlog).  However, I would like to set the property "Remaining work" for this parent element and not for the subordinate work item.

Answer (score 0):

On the backlog, you can specify columns and the quick add panel configuration. Check this:

1. [Set default columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2020#set-default-columns)
2. [Customize the quick add panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2020#customize-the-quick-add-panel)

Use `witadmin`  to [import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=azure-devops-2020).